# Cannot serve static files in a Go Gorilla server

Tags: go, static, webserver

I am playing with a small toy server to learn Go web programming.

My project directory structure has the following `public` directory:

```
public\
  | style.css
```

The permissions on `public` and `style.css` are `r-x` and `r--` for everyone.

In `main.go`, I have the following lines:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.Handle("/static/",
  http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", router))
```

Every time I call `http://localhost:3001/static/style.css`
the server returns a 404.

I have tried all combinations of leading and trailing slashes in the paths, but none make any difference.

I am running Go v1.5.3 on Ubuntu 15.10 (x64).

Comment: Only the path `/static` is handled by mux; any sub-paths are not. You'll have to tell mux to handle things matching `/static/*`.

Comment: I just tried changing the `Handle` call to `Handle("/static/.*", ...` and `Handle("/static/*", ...`. Neither worked.

Comment: `/static/{.*}` will work

Comment: That worked! (Finally, after many hours). Make your comments into a proper answer so I can up-vote it and select it as the chosen one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can serve any requests to a file in `/static/` from a folder called `public`.

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
//router.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))
router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))))
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", router))
```

Comment: I am certain I tried that earlier, but it is working now. Thanks.